# How can i use the environment variable in gulpfile.js file Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

> I have gulp file in root directory but the environment files are under
>   `src/environment`. How can i externalize the environment variables so
>   i can used variable values in root directory file!

Comment: I use export keyword before the variable to expor from environment

Comment: @canerandagio Please add the answer

Answer (score 0):

I provide an example of the traditional method of using the variables declared in environment.ts
**How to export variable:**

```
//environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false
};

export const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

**How to import variable:**

```
//some.component.ts
import { serverUrl } from 'src/environments/environment';
...
this.http.get<any>(serverUrl + 'registerError', options)
```

Note: the environment.ts file is not used for the production phase, in the case of the production phase the variables to be exported must be declared in environment.prod.ts,
I hope all this helps you